# Why can't Hall effect sensors detect electromagnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism

I read that no matter how powerful the electromagnetic field, the HE sensor won't budge.

I'm trying to develop a way to sense neodymium magnets from 12" away, and understanding the differences helps with that. If it doesn't, then delete the post.

Comment: Please provide a reference.

Comment: "*Only in the presence of non-electromagnetism does it respond*." - "*Why can't Hall effect sensors detect electromagnetism*". Are you saying that the output is inverted? And you want to invert it? Or are you just being unlucky?

Comment: One word, magnetometer

Comment: What you read is incorrect. There are current sensors that consist of a hall effect sensor measuring the field created by the current passing through the wire that is run through them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hall Effect (HE) sensors don't detect a lot of things, electrical field, smell, sound, and plenty of others. What they **do** detect is the magnetic field component normal to the element averaged over the response time of any limited bandwidth amplifier that follows the Hall element.

I'm not entirely clear what you mean by 'electromagnetism', but if a HE sensor doesn't respond to it, then I'm guessing it's something whose magnetic field component has a DC value which is zero when averaged over a suitable time.

Commercial IC Hall sensors tend to have a bandwidth in the kHz ballpark, so should be able to respond to mains and audio magnetic fields as well as DC fields, and not to those of radio waves and light.

Comment: A neo 12" away will have a DC magnetic field, so should, in principle, be detectable by an HE element. In practice, the drift of the HE, the strength of earth's field and any changing fields other than the target will set a lower limit on what output you can ascribe to signal (your target neo) and to noise (all the other effects), and so whether you can confident that you've detected your target.